# Twitter-Bootstrap-3 Carousel Modifications

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So guys, I have a carousel which works perfectly. Now I want to be able to modify it slightly so heres my script:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"  id="1"> 
            <center>Images go here!</center>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="2"> 
            <center>Imsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf</center>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="3"> 
            <center>Imasdfsdfsdfsdfre!</center>
        </div>       
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

    <br /><br /> 
    <div class="container">
        <ul style="float:left; margin-top: 200px; display:inline-block;">
            <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">Dashobard</a></li>
            <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev next">Timeline</a></li>
            <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">Visionboard</a></li>                                    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works as you would expect - now underneath I would like to have 3 links say, link1, link2, link3 that when you click it changes the slide in the carousel, in addition to this I am looking to ad a captionhttp://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/CbtT9/ underneath each of those links. see my example image - I have tried using the current controls and tried to modify them with no success.

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/CbtT9/)

[image: An example of how I need the slider to behave. So the links control the image and also the captions below.]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of this please

Comment: @AndrewMatthew Added it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/vk9Zy/embedded/result/) this is what you have to do:

HTML code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item" id="id1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/888&text=Item 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="id2">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/aaa&text=Item 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="id3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/444&text=Item 3" />
        </div>     
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>  

<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript:slideTo('0')">Dashobard</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript: slideTo('1')">Timeline</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="javascript: slideTo('2')">Visionboard</a></li>                                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function slideTo(valoare){
    if (valoare == 0) $('#myCarousel').carousel(0)
    if (valoare == 1) $('#myCarousel').carousel(1)
    if (valoare == 2) $('#myCarousel').carousel(2)    
}
```

And the CSS code i've used for this example:

```
#myCarousel {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.carousel-linked-nav,
.item img {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-linked-nav {
  width: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;   
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {margin: 0;}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/vk9Zy/)

This example uses `.carousel(number)`

**Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).**

Update 1:

- Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/uDWQ8/embedded/result/)
- Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/uDWQ8/)

Update 2:

- Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/BGC2L/embedded/result/)
- Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/BGC2L/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this..

http://bootply.com/113737

This example uses the `data-target` and `data-slide-to` navigate to specific slide.

Comment: That is 90% what I wanted that is excellent! Have you got any idea o how I would be able to add captions for each slide underneath those boxes depending on which slide you have targeted?

Comment: is there a way to ad the captions underneath the 3 links and change according to which slide you are on?