# Carousel indicators to target slides

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

So I wish to target slides with the indicators in Twitter-Bootstrap-3 but having some difficulty in doing so.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" data-id="1">
      <img src="/assets/example/bg_suburb.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
          <p><small>This is an example layout with carousel that uses the Bootstrap 3 styles.</small></p>
        </p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-id="2">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
          <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-id="3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X500">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
          <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="javascript:;" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>  
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->


 <script>

$('.carousel-indicators li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#myCarousel').carousel($(this).data('slide-to')-1); 
});

</script>
```

I need to change the indicators to words of my choosing and also add captions to each slide not siting on top of the slide so the indicators to be underneath the carousel with the caption underneath the indicators too. I have tried all manners of things but getting nowhere.

Comment: Is this different than your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787751/twitter-bootstrap-3-carousel-modifications

Comment: Yes - I have now come alot further